# MSVC errors on out-of-line definitions of methods of class templates with constrained-auto NTTP

Tags: c++, visual-c++, c++20

I'm writing a classs template with a non-type template parameter.
The NTTP has placeholder type, as in `template<auto A>`.

I want to constrain the type of `A` with a concept, like `template<std::integral auto A>`.

**Working example** (compiles on GCC/Clang/MSVC)**:**

```cpp
template<std::integral auto A>
struct Foo
{
    void bar() {}
}
```

This works fine as long as all methods/constructors/etc. are implemented directly.
However, if I move the implementation out-of-line, MSVC refuses to compile:

**Broken example** (compiles on GCC/Clang, doesn't compile on MSVC)**:**

```cpp
template<std::integral auto A>
struct Foo
{
    void bar();
};

template<std::integral auto A>
void Foo<A>::bar()
{}
```

with the following error message emitted at the out-of-line definition:

```
error C2039: 'bar': is not a member of 'Foo<A>'
note: see declaration of 'Foo<A>'
error C2447: '{': missing function header (old-style formal list?)
```

**[Reproducible example on godbolt](https://godbolt.org/#g:!((g:!((g:!((h:codeEditor,i:(filename:%271%27,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:1,lang:c%2B%2B,selection:(endColumn:1,endLineNumber:12,positionColumn:1,positionLineNumber:12,selectionStartColumn:1,selectionStartLineNumber:12,startColumn:1,startLineNumber:12),source:%27%23include+%3Cconcepts%3E%0A%0Atemplate%3Cstd::integral+auto+A%3E%0Astruct+Foo%0A%7B%0A%09void+bar()%3B%0A%7D%3B%0A%0Atemplate%3Cstd::integral+auto+A%3E%0Avoid+Foo%3CA%3E::bar()%0A%7B%7D%0A%27),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27C%2B%2B+source+%231%27,t:%270%27)),k:50.14861534000291,l:%274%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27),(g:!((h:conformance,i:(compilers:!((compilerId:vcpp_v19_latest_x64,options:%27/std:c%2B%2B20%27),(compilerId:clang1600,options:%27-std%3Dc%2B%2B20%27),(compilerId:g132,options:%27-std%3Dc%2B%2B20%27)),editorid:1,langId:c%2B%2B,libs:!()),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27Conformance+Viewer+(Editor+%231)+3/15%27,t:%270%27)),k:49.8513846599971,l:%274%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27)),l:%272%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,t:%270%27)),version:4)**

Some observations:

- The error *disappears* if I remove the constraint.
- The error *stays* if I move the constraint to a `requires` clause (`template<auto A> requires std::integral<A>`).
- The template class doesn't need to be instantiated for the error to occur.

Possible workarounds:

- `static_assert` the `decltype(A)` instead of constraining `A` directly (has slightly different semantics)
- Don't separate method definitions from their declarations
- Find a case-by-case workaround, like `template<std::size_t N, std::array<int, N> A>` instead of `template<array_of<int> auto A>` for an imagined concept `array_of<elem_type>` (more template parameters → clutter)

Is this a bug in MSVC, or is the code not standard-compliant?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is this a bug in MSVC, or is the code not standard-compliant?

This is an MSVC bug and it has been [reported here](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/Concepts-cause-external-member-function/1629668?q=defining+member+function+enabled+with+concept).
Since the bug report is still *Under consideration*, it is unclear when it will be resolved.

In addition, there is a [similar bug](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/MSVC-error-C2244-when-defining-member-fu/10090884?q=is+not+a+member+of+concept) about the constrained member function that cannot define outside a class, which hasn't been resolved either.